# How to get data from CSV file to struct by C language?

Tags: c

I have an csv file (delimited by commas). I want to get data in this file to struct. But it's not work correct. And I want get data from row 2 (ignore header).
Sorry if my English not good.
Thank you for your help.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct Student
{
    char id[7];
    char firstname[50];
    char lastname[50]; 
    char gender[6];
    char birthday[10];
    char department[5];
    char city[50];
};

int main()
{
    struct Student st[100];
    int n=0;   
    FILE *filename;
    filename = fopen("student.csv","r");
    while (!feof(filename))
    {
        fscanf(filename,"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]",st[n].id,st[n].firstname,st[n].lastname,st[n].gender,st[n].birthday, st[n].department,st[n].city);
        n++;
    }    
    fclose(filename);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].id);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].firstname);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].lastname);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].gender);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].birthday);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].department);
    printf("%s\n",st[0].city);
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: To make life simple: put an fgets(...) in place of feof(...), then use sscanf(...) instead of fscanf(...)

Comment: My teacher require I have to use fscanf

Comment: What, more precisely, do you mean by "it's not work correct"? *How* does it not work correctly? What happens? Anyway, `while(!feof(...))` is [nearly always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: I want to get data from row 2:,3...The result will be: st[0].id: 6929245 and st[0].firstname:Martin......

Comment: Just understand `fscanf()` will provide a *fragile* way to read the .csv file where one formatting error will corrupt the read from that point forward unless you add code to consume the remainder of the line in the event of a *Matching-Failure*. Far better to read the complete line with `fgets()` into a buffer (character array) and then parse from the buffer with `sscanf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In CSV format at the end of each line, you usually don't have a comma, If that is the case in your CSV file too, then change the format you are providing to `fscanf`,

from this,

```
"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,]"
```

to this,

```
"%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]"
```

if you try to read till next comma `,` for the `city` field too, then you will end up reading the string `city\n6929245` to `st[n].city` which is wrong and will result in an incorrect reading pattern and might end up in segfault.

And to avoid printing the first line, you can skip the index 0 in your `st` array, because the first line that you read will be stored in the 0th index of the `st` array and from index 1 will be your data.

Comment: How I can fix this problem you said?

Comment: the last %[^,] should be changed to %[^\n],  see the difference in my highlighted code.

Comment: I've just fix my code like you said. But when I run, I have the result of st[1].id is 6929245Martin and st[2].id is 1990356Cateryth

Comment: do you have a comma separating the student id and the first name fields in the file?

Comment: you can check the actual contents of the file by opening it in a text editor rather than on an excel sheet.

Comment: Yes, I have comma between Student ID and firstname.

Comment: then it should work. I have tested with your code too.